# Create a column based on comparing with a vector and the get the closest number in R

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I have the following table in R Dataframe:

[image]

I want to compare col2 to a vector [image]

and based on the value that is closest to an element in the vector I want to create Col3 as shown below:
[image]

How do I do this in R programming?

Comment: Please don't add your data as images. Use `dput` to share data, read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this as follows:

```
# create a minimal example data.frame and 
# vector of values to match
df <- data.frame(x = seq(0.1, 1, 0.1))

set.seed(1)
v  <- df$x + rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 0.1)

# create a vector z that stores values from v that 
# are closest to values in the ith element of df$x
z <- c()
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  z[i] = v[which.min(abs(df$x[i] - v))]
}

# assign the new object z to the data.frame
df$z <- z
df
```

Which returns:

```
x          z
1  0.1 0.03735462
2  0.2 0.21643714
3  0.3 0.21836433
4  0.4 0.51795316
5  0.5 0.51795316
6  0.6 0.55952808
7  0.7 0.74874291
8  0.8 0.74874291
9  0.9 0.87383247
10 1.0 0.96946116
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rich. That worked. This is awesome.